# Access features with click events in SceneView ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: feature-layer, events, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to access features of a featurelayer in a SceneView on click event. I have seen [this example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=view-hittest) from Esri's documentation for ArcGIS API for JavaScript but this example is for a MapView. When I change MapView to SceneView, the graphic property of the object that is returned by view.hitTest is always null, even if I click on a feature.

I simply just replaced every MapView in the code to SceneView. The map loads fine, click event works (i.e. it returns x,y coordinates of the click).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [API reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html#hitTest):

> FeatureLayer.hitTest(screenPoint)
>
> ... Draped graphics (i.e. graphics in layers where the [elevation mode](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#elevationInfo) is `on-the-ground`) are currently **not** returned from this method, even when they intersect the input screen point.

because `on-the-ground` is the default elevation mode for feature layers with polyline geometry, it is currently necessary to set the property manually in the sample you referenced in order for `hitTest()` to return what you want.

```
var layer = new FeatureLayer({
  // ...
  elevationInfo: { mode: "absolute-height" }
});
```

Comment: you're very welcome